# How is Apache 1.3 compressing?

Tags: httpd.conf, gzip, apache-1.3, compression, containers

More specifically, I would like suggestions as to how my server is encoding in gzip compressed format.  We have once OC4J container that serves gzip transfer encoding, and others do not.  Trying to turn compression off in the working container, we have not only commented out compression done in httpd.conf but put in command to explicitly disallow gzip, and the content still comes back gzip.  What is actually doing the compression?

Nothing in virtualhosts.conf and I see nothing in META-INF web.xml . There is no .htaccess file.  Tried adding the same AddEncoding directives into virtualhosts.conf for the non-working host, but no luck... that container is still serving uncompressed content.  We are running Apache 1.3 (yes I know it's old) and mod_deflate/mod_gzip are not loaded modules.  zlib isn't being used and Apache is so old that that mod_gzip and mod_deflate are not in play, so I need to figure out how gzip is happening.

Currently the responses from the non-working containers have no Transfer Encoding in the header, or it is in chunked format.  I know most people believe responses are either gzip or chunked, but I was reading that a response can be both gzip and chunked, as long as it happens in the right order.

UPDATE
Recursively checked all .conf files and I am just not seeing where this is being done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if mod_mime fails, it executes a conf file not mentioned in any of the other .conf files?  magic.conf has encoding in it, so this must be it.

Looking forward to upgrading, but hope this helps anyone else living 12 years ago.